# Find records based on its other parent child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have this associations:

```
class Ship < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :captain_profiles
 has_many :captains, through: :captain_profiles
end

class CaptainProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :captain
  belongs_to :ship
end

class Captain < ApplicationRecord 
  has_one :captain_profile
  has_many :schedules
end

class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :captain
end
```

And I need list of all ships that are ready to be taken to the sea. In other words I have to find all ships that has at least one Captain with at least one of his schedules.

I thought about merging two inner joins as I need Ships which has Captains which has Schedules.
I tried `Captain.includes(:schedules).where("schedule.id IS NOT NULL")` and so with Ships but it does not work. Could someone explain me what am I doing wrong and how shall I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `joins` which generates `INNER JOIN`.

```
Ship.joins(captains: :schedules)
```